# How to associate allowed_domains with start_urls in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a broad scrapy crawler which takes a csv file of about 20,000 rows. The file has a name, start_url and allowed domain column. See below:

```
Name               start_url               allowed_domain
place1             https://place1.co.uk    place1.co.uk
place2             https://place2.co.uk    place2.co.uk
place3             https://place3.co.uk    place3.co.uk
```

A sample of my crawler code is below:

```
class FinalSpider(CrawlSpider): 

    name = "final"
    df = pd.read_csv("places.csv")
    start_urls = df["start_url"].values.tolist()

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
                'my_spider.middlewares.MySpiderDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
        },
        'SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.pqueues.DownloaderAwarePriorityQueue',
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 100,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'RETRY_ENABLED': False,
        'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True
    }

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=(df["allowed_domain"].values.tolist())), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)


    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # do stuff
```

The problem is that my crawler is allowed to follow links that are in any of the allowed domains, not just the one associated with the start_url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign `allowed_domain` for each link in `start_urls`

You will have to filter urls inside `process_request` method of `DownloaderMiddleware`

Here is your Spider code

```
class FinalSpider(CrawlSpider): 

    name = "final"

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
                'my_spider.middlewares.MySpiderDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
        },
        'SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.pqueues.DownloaderAwarePriorityQueue',
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 100,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'RETRY_ENABLED': False,
        'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True
    }

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True),)

    def start_requests(self):
        df = pd.read_csv("places.csv")
        for key, row in df.iterrows():
            yield Request(url=row['start_url'],
                callback=self.parse_item,
                meta={'allowed_domain': row['allowed_domain']})
```

Here is Middleware code

```
import tldextract
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

class MySpiderDownloaderMiddleware(object): 

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        site = tldextract.extract(request.url)
        site = "{}.{}".format(site.domain, site.suffix)

        if request.meta['allowed_domain'] not in site:
            raise IgnoreRequest("Filtered offsite request")
```